# How to replace an int value with a string in c

Tags: arrays, c, char

If user press, then I want to replace it with "Unknown". I thought we can do convertion like that. Is there any way to do it. I just want to do it in that way instead of typing by printf"unknown"

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char replace[20] = "Unknown";
    int press = 0;

    printf("Enter a number") ;
    scanf("%d", &press);

    if(press==2)
    {
      press = replace[20] ; 
    }
    else
    printf("%d", press) ;
}
```

Comment: You have `scanf("%d", press);` —— you need: `scanf("%d", &press);` (or, better, `if (scanf("%d", &press)  != 1) { …report I/O error… }`).

Comment: You have `printf("%s", replace[20] );` —— you need: `printf("%s", replace);` (though I'd argue that there should be a newline at the end of the format string: `printf("%s\n", replace);`.  Using `replace[20]` attempts to pass a single character where a string is expected, and furthermore addresses outside the bounds of the `replace` array (where the element indexes are 0..19 because C counts from zero).

Comment: I updated the question. My question was this actually.

Comment: You can't store the string `Unknown` in an integer variable, so you can't do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You already updated the first scanf(), and here how you could do the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Enter a number: ") ;
    int press;
    if(scanf("%d", &press) != 1) {
        printf("scanf failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if(press==2)
        printf("%s\n", "Unknown");
    else
        printf("%d\n", press) ;
}
```

Here is example runs:

```
$ ./a.out
Enter a number: 1
1
$ ./a.out
Enter a number: 2
Unknown
```